# Sequelize Query Where not equal and Other Conditions

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to make the query id not equal in Sequelize.

Here is my current sequelize query:

```js
return db.Area.findAll({
    where: { id: { $ne: Id },
    slug: conditions.slug }
})
```

The resulting SQL Query:

```sql
*SELECT `id`, `title`, `name`, `titleL1`, `nameL1`, `level`, `slug`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `ParentId` FROM `Areas` AS `Area` 
WHERE `Area`.`id` = '[object Object]' AND `Area`.`slug` = 'Nakyal-1';*
```

This part is not correct:

```sql
WHERE `Area`.`id` = '[object Object]'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if it is your case, but I had problems using shortcut '$' operators from sequelize. You might try this approach:

```
const Op = require('sequelize').Op;
***
where: { id: { [Op.ne]: Id }... }
```